# Node js- req.body empty or undefined when handling ajax post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

this question asked by many users I saw all the solution and try to implement them but it is not working for me.
I am trying to get data in node js function which is sent by ajax.
my code in  app.js

```
var express    = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var app = express()

app.post('/'uploadFileProduction',jsonParser,function(req,res){
     console.log("Hooorrey!!!!")
     console.log(req.body)

})
```

my ajax code part is

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#submit_modal').click(function(e) {
           console.log('desired event fire!!!!!!!')
         e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
                data.title = "title";
                data.message = "message";

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'uploadFileProduction',
               data: JSON.stringify(data),

         });
     });
    });
</script>
```

when I am hitting this ajax function, I am getting null in body.
I tried following solution but no luck

[req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

[Express.js POST req.body empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294730/express-js-post-req-body-empty)

[Node.js req.body empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948460/node-js-req-body-empty)

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/101

When I am printing req in node js, it is printing all data but in body it is {}  only.

Please help.

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. The code you show has Syntax and Runtime Errors and won't run at all.

Comment: @t.niese I wrote my function here in which I am trying to receive data and ajax script.

Comment: Yes but the server side code is completely broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is because you send the body as a JSON object, but doesn't specify the contentType. The server doesn't know how to parse your body without knowing the correct content type. You should add it to make things work:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'uploadFileProduction',
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" // <- this is what you should add
});
```

Comment: I was missing this content type only. thanks it is working fine now. thanks a lot